# How to find subset(s) in a dataframe column and return <subsetOf - >?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I just used .groupby and .agg to make my df as follows -

```
  Name inclusionId            
    A   1 , 2                  
    B   1 , 3                  
    C   5 , 7                  
    D   5 , 2 , 9 , 7 , 1     
    E   2 , 1 , 9
```

Now I want to check whether these are ***subsets*** of each other or not.
Need output like below -

```
 Name inclusionId            Subset of -
    A   1 , 2                  E
    B   1 , 3                  No
    C   5 , 7                  D
    D   5 , 2 , 9 , 7 , 1      No
    E   2 , 1 , 9              D
```

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can select

1. all rows and limited columns
2. all columns and limited rows
3. limited rows and limited columns

**you can select columns like this**:

```
dataframe['column']
```

or

```
dataframe[['column1', 'column2' ]]
```

now **to select the rows you point out the column and set a condition that only certain rows meet** like the following:

```
population_500 = housing[housing['population']>500]
```

in here we select rows having population greater than 500

**you can also use** `dataframe.loc(row_number/s)` **to select certain rows for example**:

```
dataframe.loc[[1,5,7]]
```

and **you can select both rows and columns also using** `.loc()`:

```
dataframe.loc[1:7,['column_1', 'column_2']]
```

where 1 and 7 refer to the rows numbers

**you can also use** `.iloc()` **to select a subset of rows and columns**:

```
dataframe.iloc[[2,3,6], [3, 5]]
```

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Being specific to the question, I am not able to successfully get the desired result which shows whether it is a subset or not.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit complicative

```
s = df.set_index('Name').inclusionId.str.get_dummies(',')
s = s.dot(s.T)
diag = np.diag(s).copy()
np.fill_diagonal(s.values,0)
df['new'] = s.eq(diag).T.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1].values
Out[74]: 
  Name inclusionId  new
0    A         1,2  D,E
1    B         1,3     
2    C         5,7    D
3    D   5,2,9,7,1     
4    E       2,1,9    D
```

Comment: s = df.set_index('inclusionName').inclusionId.std.get_dummies(',')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_dummies'

(changed 'str' to 'std' because - "Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?")